# Webstorm weirdest HTML parsing error: expecting new line or semicolon

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

I get an error when I give a button the following styles "btn btn-large". There HTML shows the following error: expecting new line or semicolon.

When I change the tag to `<a>` everything becomes alright.

When I try to build with grunt with the `<button>` tag the minification of the HTML fails which means it is not necessarily a Webstorm issue...

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: can't recreate. Can you attach HTML that shows up your issue?

Comment: edit your answer to include _relevant_ code from: [input HTML file], [Gruntfile.js], [output HTML file].

Comment: Please also try `File | Invalidate Caches...` -- just in case.